# How to dynamically size elements in windows forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows forms application written in VB.NET (I'm comfortable taking suggestions in C# too) and I have two DataGridViews aligned vertically, so one above the other. I would like to be able to maximise the window and have the DataGridViews expand with the window so it looks roughly the same but bigger.

I have tried using the docking and anchoring controls and haven't found a way to do it without overlapping or leaving giant empty spaces which it should be expanding into.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dock the first grid to the top and the second to fill, however the fill docking must be executed before the top docking (you can arrange that in the document outline tool window).
This solution will leave the first grid always in the same height.
You can also handle the form Resize event and calculate the position and size of the grids yourself.

Comment: Thanks. So with this method the top docked one would not scale downwards?

Comment: No it won't, but if you'll use the second option I mentioned and you won't use docking you'll get what you need

Comment: I can make this work. I don't really want to get into calculating the sizes myself because I know I would spend far too much time making it perfect when I only need to fix a minor issue :)